# How do I narrow down querySelectorAll to a specific ID?

Tags: javascript

I've got the following MVC Razor code and what I'm looking to do is get a list of all the hidden values of a table into a JS list.

I was eventually able to get a list of all of the hidden fields but it also includes some other hidden fields on the page I don't need. How would I narrow it down to just the hidden fields with an ID="RID" and if I could get just the values of those hidden fields that would help even more.

Here is what I'm doing to write out the table

```
<tr>
    <td>@item.Base</td>
    <td>@item.Seat</td>
    <td>
        @item.Equipment
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RID, new { Value = item.RID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the JS I used to get the list of all Hidden fields.

```
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]');
```

I tried this from an example I found but it didn't work.

```
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"] RID');
and 
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"] #RID');
```

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id. Use a class instead.

Comment: I didn't think you could add a class to a hidden field?

Comment: The space before the ID in your selector breaks it. `'input[type="hidden"]#RID'` While it's true that IDs should be unique, `.querySelectorAll` does search for and return multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: ...a `class` attribute can go on any Element.

Comment: add a specific class to the hidden ones you want and query it, otherwise, do your way then filter the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space before the ID in your selector breaks it, because the empty space causes it to look for *descendants* of the `input` with that ID. Removing the space checks the ID on the elements themselves.

```
'input[type="hidden"]#RID'
```

While it's true that IDs should be unique, `.querySelectorAll` does search for and return multiple elements with the same ID. Still, it would be much better form to make that `id` into a `class` and select that way

To get the values, use `Array.from`, and pass a function as the second argument that returns the value.

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]#RID');
let vals = Array.from(elems, el => el.value);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation as well.